# Wifi router keeps needing to be restarted. Why?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, wireless-router

The router (TP-Link's TL-WR840N) is connected to a switch, which is connected to the ISP provided router.

The internet works well and everything is OK from a few minutes to a couple of days, and then the devices connected to it would either show connected, but no internet...or get disconnected and not be able to connect back. So the router then has to be rebooted, after which the problem would be resolved for, again, from a few minutes to a few days.
Tried reseting it. Problem didn't go away.

What could be the reason for this and how to troubleshoot?

Answer (score 0):

> The router (TP-Link's TL-WR840N) is connected to a switch, which is
> connected to the ISP provided router.

1. Try connecting the router to the ISP modem and leave out the switch.
2. Update the Firmware in your Router to the latest firmware.
3. Do a Factory Reset, and then set up the connection to the ISP modem and wireless access again.
4. If all of the above fails to improve the situation, then consider replacing the router with a new router.